# How to add string to each button in generic list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a generic list of buttons like this:

```
public List<GameObject> button_list = new List<GameObject>();
```

I added a listener each of those buttons in the list.

```
foreach(GameObject go in button_list)
        {
            go.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => StartCoroutine(ChangeScene()));
        }

private IEnumerator ChangeScene(string toLoad, string toUnload)
    {
        yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(toLoad);
        yield return SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(toUnload);
    }
```

Unity's inspector shows a dropdown where I can specify the number of buttons.

Also I need to add to each button a string where can specify what scene is needed to be loaded. It has to be seen in inspector, like public strings.
I mean, those strings toLoad and toUnload have to be unique for each button in list.
I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Do each button need a specific string?

Comment: There is a string toLoad, which specifies scene that needs to be loaded. For each button in list this string has to have different value

Comment: Check my answer, it should solve your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit involved but then it's easier to use, you pick scene assets directly instead of buggy strings.

[image]

**The object:**

```
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[Serializable]
public sealed class CustomAction
{
    public Button Button;
    public string Scene1;
    public string Scene2;
}
```

**The object drawer:**

Here we use `SceneAsset` because it's handy in the editor to pick scenes instead of strings, but since it's an editor type it won't be available in final game; we just do the conversion to a string.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(CustomAction))]
internal sealed class CustomActionPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        property.serializedObject.Update();

        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        position.height = height;

        property.isExpanded = EditorGUI.Foldout(position, property.isExpanded, new GUIContent(property.displayName));

        position.y += height;

        if (property.isExpanded)
        {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

            var button = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(CustomAction.Button));
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, button);
            position.y += height;

            var scene1 = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(CustomAction.Scene1));
            DrawScenePicker(position, scene1);
            position.y += height;

            var scene2 = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(CustomAction.Scene2));
            DrawScenePicker(position, scene2);
            position.y += height;

            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }

        property.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void DrawScenePicker(Rect position, SerializedProperty property)
    {
        using (var scope = new EditorGUI.ChangeCheckScope())
        {
            var label = EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, null, property);
            var value = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<SceneAsset>(property.stringValue);
            var field = EditorGUI.ObjectField(position, label, value, typeof(SceneAsset), false);

            if (!scope.changed)
                return;

            var asset = field as SceneAsset;

            property.stringValue = asset != null ? AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(asset) : null;
        }
    }

    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        if (property.isExpanded)
            height *= 4;

        return height;
    }
}
```

**The behavior:**

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SetupActions : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CustomAction[] Actions;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // AddListener is non-persistent so register again
        RegisterButtons();
    }

    private static IEnumerator ChangeScene(string toLoad, string toUnload)
    {
        yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(toLoad);
        yield return SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(toUnload);
    }

    public void RegisterButtons()
    {
        foreach (var action in Actions)
        {
            var scene1 = action.Scene1;
            var scene2 = action.Scene2;
            var button = action.Button;
            button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
            button.onClick.AddListener(() => { StartCoroutine(ChangeScene(scene1, scene2)); });
        }
    }
}
```

**The behavior editor:**

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(SetupActions))]
internal class SetupActionsEditor : Editor
{
    private bool IsDirty;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        var property = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(SetupActions.Actions));

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property);

        IsDirty |= EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck();

        DoApplyButton();

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void DoApplyButton()
    {
        using (new EditorGUI.DisabledGroupScope(!IsDirty))
        {
            if (!GUILayout.Button("Apply"))
                return;

            var actions = (SetupActions) target;

            actions.RegisterButtons();

            IsDirty = false;
        }
    }
}
```

TODO: adapt this to your code

Comment: If already jumping into editor scripts anyway you should make it a [`ReorderableList`](https://www.google.com/amp/s/va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist/amp/)